# What did Robert lie to Miles about?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-equalizer-2

In *The Equalizer 2* (2018), while pointing a gun at Miles, Robert talks to him because he is hanging with a gang:

> Robert: See, you know what they are up there? They liars, and so am I.
>   See what happens when you deal with a liar? See what happens?  **I lied
>   to your little punk-ass**.

What did Robert lie to Miles about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## He didn't

Robert is just trying **to make a point** to Miles that bad things happen when you deal with liars.

He says that he's a liar and that he lied to Miles because he's currently pointing a gun at him and threatening (apparently) to kill him to demonstrate what happens when dealing with liars.